# Type safety: Unchecked cast from JSONArray to ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>

Tags: java, casting

In one of my programming courses, I was given the task of creating a class that reads and writes json to a file.

I used the json.simple library, but quickly realized that almost all lines received a "Type safety warning"?

I then tried to use ArrayList and HashMap as much as possible since JSONObject and JSONArray extender these. From what I understood, this was an issue.

I am quite new to programming and would greatly appreciate being some tips, also when it comes to how I solved the task.

How do I get rid of these type of saftey warnings?

My code :

`

```
//imports
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadAndWrite {
    /**
     * This is a class for reading and writing to the userData file stored in the users home directory.
     * The file is stored in json format. The classes are first converted to json format and then written to the file.
     * The classes are then read from the file and converted back to the classes.
     */

    /**
     * For the first version of the application we will only have one user. 
     * This is why we have a dummy name for the user. To parse the classes to json
     * we are using the json-simple library. JSONObjects 
     */
    private static String dummyName = "dummyName";
    private static String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "loftUserData.json";
    private JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    private Collection<User> userClasses = new ArrayList<User>();
    private Collection<Workout> workoutsClasses = new ArrayList<Workout>();
    private Collection<Exercise> exercisesClasses = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private Collection<Set> setsClasses = new ArrayList<Set>();
    
    
    /**
     * Private method for setting up a set class to json format.
     * @param list of sets
     * @return ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> -> sets in json format
     */
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> setSetsJsonArray(List<Set> list) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> setsArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        int i = 0;
        for (Set set : list) {
            HashMap<String, Object> setJson = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            setJson.put("setNumber", ++i);
            setJson.put("weight", set.getWeight());
            setJson.put("reps", set.getReps());
            setsArray.add(setJson);
        }
        return setsArray;
    }
    /**
     * Private method for setting up a exercise class to json format.
     * @param list of exercises
     * @return ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> -> exercises in json format
     */
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> setExercisesJsonArray(List<Exercise> list) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>  exercisesArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        for (Exercise exercise : list) {
            HashMap<String, Object> exerciseJson = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            exerciseJson.put("exerciseName", exercise.getName());
            exerciseJson.put("sets", setSetsJsonArray(exercise.getSets()));
            exercisesArray.add(exerciseJson);
        }
        return exercisesArray;
    }
    /**
     * Private method for setting up a workout class to json format.
     * @param workout
     * @return HashMap<String, Object> -> workout in json format
     */
    private HashMap<String, Object> formatWorkoutClassToJson(Workout workout) {
        HashMap<String, Object> workoutJson = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        workoutJson.put("exercises", setExercisesJsonArray(workout.getExercises()));
        workoutJson.put("date", workout.getDate().toString());
        
        return workoutJson;
    }

    //Writing a workout class to the userData file in json format
    /** 
     * The method to be used for writing a workout class to the userData file in json format.
     * @param workout
     */
    public void writeWorkoutToUser(Workout workout) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> existingData = readDataFromFile();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> users = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        
        HashMap<String, Object> user = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    
        // Setting up user
        if (existingData == null) {
            user.put("name", dummyName);
            user.put("workouts", new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>());
        } else {
            HashMap<String, Object> userDummy = existingData.get(0);
            user = userDummy;
        }
    
        // Adding to user
        HashMap<String, Object> workoutInJSONFormat = this.formatWorkoutClassToJson(workout);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> workoutsJsonArray = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) user.get("workouts");
        workoutsJsonArray.add(workoutInJSONFormat);
    
        users.add(user);
        JSONArray jsonFormat = new JSONArray();
        jsonFormat.addAll(users);
    
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(fileLocation)) {    
            file.write(jsonFormat.toJSONString()); 
            file.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Private method for reconstructing the user class from a JSONArray format.
     * @param users JSONArray of users
     * @return ArrayList of users, in our case there is only one user.
     */
    private ArrayList<User> classReconstructor(JSONArray users) {
        for (Object userObject : users) {
            JSONObject user = (JSONObject) userObject;
            String name = (String) user.get("name");
            
            JSONArray workouts = (JSONArray) user.get("workouts");
            for (Object workoutObject : workouts) {
                JSONObject workout = (JSONObject) workoutObject;
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse((String) workout.get("date"));

                JSONArray exercises = (JSONArray) workout.get("exercises");
                for (Object exerciseObject : exercises) {
                    JSONObject exercise = (JSONObject) exerciseObject;
                    String exerciseName = (String) exercise.get("exerciseName");

                    JSONArray sets = (JSONArray) exercise.get("sets");
                    for (Object setObject : sets) {
                        JSONObject set = (JSONObject) setObject;
                        int weight = ((Long) set.get("weight")).intValue();
                        int reps = ((Long) set.get("reps")).intValue();

                        Set newSet = new Set(weight, reps);
                        setsClasses.add(newSet);
                    }
                    Exercise newExercise = new Exercise(exerciseName);
                    for (Set set : setsClasses) {
                        newExercise.addSet(set);
                    }
                    exercisesClasses.add(newExercise);
                }
                Workout newWorkout = new Workout(date);
                for (Exercise exercise : exercisesClasses) {
                    newWorkout.addExercise(exercise);
                }
                workoutsClasses.add(newWorkout);
            }
            User newUser = new User(name);
            for (Workout workout : workoutsClasses) {
                newUser.addWorkout(workout);
            }
            userClasses.add(newUser);
        }
        return (ArrayList<User>) userClasses;
    }

    /**
     * Private method for reading data from the file.
     * @return JSONArray of all users. In our case there is only one user.
     */
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> readDataFromFile() {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation)){
            if (reader.ready()) {
                Object obj = parser.parse(reader);
                JSONArray users = (JSONArray) obj;
                
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> usersList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) users;

                return usersList;
            } else {
                //The file can be empty this is not an error, it just means that there is no data to read.
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // If it is not found, it will be created at a later point, so this is fine
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** 
     * The method to be used for getting the user class from the file.
     * @return User class
     */
    public User returnUserClassFromFile() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> users = readDataFromFile();
        if (users == null) {
            return new User(dummyName);
        }
        JSONArray usersJson = (JSONArray) users;
        ArrayList<User> user = this.classReconstructor(usersJson);
        User userClass = user.get(0);
        return userClass;
    }
```

Where the issue appears:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> workoutsJsonArray = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) user.get("workouts");
```

```
jsonFormat.addAll(users);
```

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> usersList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) users;
```

The warning messages :
[image]

I have tried to use ArrayList and HashMap insted of JSONArray and JSONObject

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type safety warnings you are encountering are because you are working with collections of ***HashMap<String, Object>*** and trying to cast them to more specific types. While this casting can be done, it's not type-safe because the generic types of your collections are not explicitly defined, leading to unchecked type conversions.

To get rid of these type safety warnings, you should consider using JSON libraries that allow you to work with Java objects directly, such as Google's ***Gson*** or ***Jackson***. These libraries will allow you to map your JSON data directly to Java classes and avoid casting issues.

Here's how you can refactor your code using the Gson library:

1. Add the Gson dependency to your project if you haven't already

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
</dependency>
```

2. Refactor your ReadAndWrite class to use Gson:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class ReadAndWrite {
    private static String dummyName = "dummyName";
    private static String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "loftUserData.json";
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    // ...

    public void writeWorkoutToUser(Workout workout) {
        List<User> existingData = readDataFromFile();
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        User user;

        if (existingData == null || existingData.isEmpty()) {
            user = new User(dummyName);
        } else {
            user = existingData.get(0);
        }

        user.addWorkout(workout);
        users.add(user);

        String jsonFormat = gson.toJson(users);

        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(fileLocation)) {
            file.write(jsonFormat);
            file.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<User> readDataFromFile() {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation)) {
            if (reader.ready()) {
                List<User> users = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType());
                return users;
            } else {
                // The file can be empty; this is not an error.
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // If it is not found, it will be created at a later point, so this is fine.
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public User returnUserClassFromFile() {
        List<User> users = readDataFromFile();

        if (users == null || users.isEmpty()) {
            return new User(dummyName);
        }

        return users.get(0);
    }
}
```

With this refactoring, you no longer need to cast between JSON collections and Java objects, making your code safer and more maintainable.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much. This is a way better solution :). However, do you have any pointers on how to add gson to our module? 

our module-info.java :

`module ui {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires gson;
    

    opens ui.controllers to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
    opens ui to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
`
Is this a total misunderstanding on how modularity works? The package for the ReadAndWrite.java is core.